# How to remove the suffix using gulp rename

Tags: gulp, gulp-rename

I wish to copy some twig files while removing the 'src' suffix
example: someCode.html.src.twig 
with the result : someCode.html.twig 
using gulp rename as I must have this change implemented for several files that all have the src suffix.

I also wish to maintain the directory structure:

example:

D: test --> formsDirectory --> someFile.html.src.twig
                           , someotherFile.html.src.twig

```
    --> SomeOtherDir   --> onemore.html.src.twig
```

result:
D: someDir --> formsDirectory --> someFile.html.twig
                           , someotherFile.html.twig

```
       --> SomeOtherDir   --> onemore.html.twig
```

I know that I can use gulp rename to remove the extension and basename however I wish to only change the suffix are illustrated. Any Help would be Great! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `gulp-ext-replace`

Example:

```
.pipe(ext_replace('twig', '.src.twig'))
```